# My ASUS UX32VD laptop's recovery partition doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, asus-laptop, factory-defaults

After HDD swap (on Windows 10) the recovery partition doesn't work.
I would like to get the contents of the "Recovery" and "Restore" partitions.

(Came from the factory with Windows 8.)

(I swapped the HDD myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem by using `assign` to mount the volumes flagged "*Recovery*" (in `diskpart`) and copying the contents of the partitions to a local location, where I could then access it to copy to the new HDD.

Edit: NB! Partition number 6 is empty.

Comment: By the way if ANYONE is experiencing this problem, then please comment here so I can send them the files.